# Is there a python function to find if a floating point number belongs to a specific range?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to find all the rows having BMI value between 15 to 20?

I tried this but it returns only 1 row which has bmi as 19.0.

```
df3[df3['bmi'].isin(np.arange(15,21))]
```

This works but i need to know a method which works without applying ciel function and directly on float values.

```
df3[df3['bmi'].apply(np.ceil).isin(range(15,22))]
```

Check image for more details.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySSqI.png)

Comment: I'm not good with Pandas, but maybe just `df3[15 <= df3['bmi'] <= 22]`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df3[(15<=df3['bmi']) & (df3['bmi']<=22)]
```